# EF Cascade delete when child property maps to SQL View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

We have the following model:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public CompanyRepresentative CompanyRepresentatives {get; set; }
}

public class CompanyRepresentative
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string RepresentativeNames {get; set; }
}
```

CompanyRepresentative is a SQL View and is mapped using the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasOptional(q => q.CompanyRepresentatives)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(q => q.MapKey("CompanyId"));
```

**The problem is that when deleting a company EF is attempting to update CompanyRepresentative setting the CompanyId to NULL which obviously fails because it is a View.**

We have tried changing the mapping to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasOptional(q => q.CompanyRepresentatives)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(q => q.MapKey("CompanyId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...which had no effect.

**Is there a way to tell EF not to try and update this property when it is deleting?**

Comment: So your company has a list of representatives, and your representatives also have a id mapped to a specific company?

Comment: The View behind CompanyRepresentatives takes a table containing a row for each company representative and displays one row for each companyId with a comma delimited string of representative names.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to delete a company? Is the `CompanyRepresentatives` property loaded in your context?

Comment: Just by removing the company from the Companies DbSet and saving changes. And no it hasn't been loaded.